# Why is react ternary operator only works in between tags?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been scratching my head over a very simple ternary operation in react native in the middle of the development. I'm using prettier integrated with `eslint` but the error does not help a lot

It wasn't detecting my ternary operation

```
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as React from "react";
import React, {StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icons: {marginBottom: -3}
});

export default function TabBarIcon(props) {
  const {type, name, focused} = props;
    return (
    { type === "Ionicons" ?
    <Ionicons
    name={name}
    size={30}
    style={styles.icons}
    color={
      focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault
    }
  /> :
    <MaterialIcons
    name={name}
    size={30}
    style={icons}
    color={
      focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault
    }
    />
  }

    );
}
```

Error:

```
["ERROR" - 3:15:41 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 3:15:41 PM] Unexpected token, expected "," (13:12)
  11 |   const {type, name, focused} = props;
  12 |  return (
> 13 |     { type === "Ionicons" ?
     |            ^
  14 |     <Ionicons
  15 |     name={name}
  16 |     size={30}
```

Then after trial and error, putting them in between React fragment seems to work. Is there any explanation to this? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

```
export default function TabBarIcon(props) {
    const { type, name, focused } = props;
    return (
        <>
            {type === "Ionicons" ? (
                <Ionicons
                    name={name}
                    size={30}
                    style={styles.icons}
                    color={
                        focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault
                    }
                />
            ) : (
                <MaterialIcons
                    name={name}
                    size={30}
                    style={icons}
                    color={
                        focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault
                    }
                />
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary operator in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296199/ternary-operator-in-react-native)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't because its my tag is not an opening tag

Comment: I changed my question as it is acting differently. I explained further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly bracket syntax is only for when you want to use some JS expression inside JSX.
In your code above it's a syntax error. The correct syntax would be something like this

```js
export default function TabBarIcon(props) {
  const { type, name, focused } = props
  return type === 'Ionicons' ? (
    <Ionicons
      name={name}
      size={30}
      style={styles.icons}
      color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
    />
  ) : (
    <MaterialIcons
      name={name}
      size={30}
      style={icons}
      color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: i can see how this should help, was going to comment to try that before looked for duplicates, might be nice to add more description why though, at least enough they know what to call it and look for to learn more :)